# Jquery Smooth Scroll not working, Tried almost everything

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's some bit of the code, I wrote -

```
      $('#go').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       var href = $('#go').attr('href');
       console.log(href)
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, )
  })
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, would appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Not sure why **what** isn't happening? What isn't working? Is it not scrolling, too slow, what? *Show what you've tried*. Your question needs to be elaborated on.

Comment: check my answer below. it should work for you if you follow the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're using a css framework like Material Design lite, then you need to use something different.

```
    $('#go').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       var href = $('#go').attr('href');
       console.log(href)
       $('.mdl-layout__content').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      },1000 )
  })
```

Wrap it into ".mdl-layout__content", instead of "html, body" as it fixes it. I had the same problem, but that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add some time value in `animate` function like `animate((),1000)` .They will give smooth effect .see the **[jquery documentation of `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

```
$('#go').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       var href = $('#go').attr('href');
       console.log(href)
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      },1000 )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to look at

1. writing HTML correctly .the link must have href with `#` inside it, in your case `<a id="go" href="#goTo">GOOO</a>`
2. check if your id's are correctly written in html and then in JQ

```js
 $('#go').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       var href = $('#go').attr('href');
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, 1000)
  })
```

```css
div {
 margin-top:100vh;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="go" href="#goTo">GOOO</a>
<div id="goTo">

</div>
```